# Where is the url mapping defined for rest api created with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-mvc

I followed the tutorial here https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
which first had me set up my pom file (i am using maven) and then had me set up the object and the "Create a resource controller"

so i did and have

```
package hello;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

The tutorials says

> Although it is possible to package this service as a traditional WAR file for deployment to an external application server, the simpler approach demonstrated below creates a standalone application.

but I am using WARs I use them instead of application so I did not create that.

However it never explains how to map "/greeting" When I launch my WAR it works but going to /greeting results in a 404 error. Which doesn't surprise me since it was never mapped anywhere.

Am I supposed to map it to web.xml somehow?

Comment: You need a web mvc configuration. Do you have one? You're not using Spring boot?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you're deploying into a container, the container will put your app at `/appName`, so you'd go to `/appName/greeting`. Spring Boot will set up an embedded container and put your application at the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you'll need to instruct the application server via the web.xml file.
If you use spring, this configuration (which is the base configuration provided by the Spring MVC template project) will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Please note the `<servlet-mapping>` element. You are telling your application server that you have a servlet called `appServlet` that is going to be mapped to `/` url-pattern. This means that every request with a URL such as `http://.../YourApplicationName/whatever` will be forwarded to your spring servlet and eventually your controllers (which will manage the `whatever` part ;-) ).

The aforementioned configuration works provided you have the following project structure:

[image]